# Permission Denied after mapping iam user with role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Can someone help me to resolve permission denied issue. let me know if anything missing or wrong.

Created new role `custom-iams-orchestration-role`for service `Elastic Container Service Task`with below policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And trusted the user with same account by adding the below policy in role

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/iams-dev-user"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

And for user `iams-dev-user` added below policy to assume role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/custom-iams-orchestration-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

But getting an issue when executing `aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:accountid:SISMANAGER-DEV-TOPIC --message testingForIamsDevUser --profile iams-dev-user --region=us-east-1` from my laptop with user `iams-user-dev` key

`User:arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/iams-dev-user is not authorized to perform`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually [assume the role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) it doesn't happen automatically.
This will give you an access key, a secret, and a session token to then use with other commands. If you dont want to assume a role then the user needs to be assigned the policy directly.

## Example

#### Use the aws cli to assume the role in question

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/custom-iams-orchestration-role --role-session-name orchestration-access-example --profile iams-dev-users
```

#### This will give you ouput containing the new **Access Key**, **Secret**, and **Session Token**:

```
"Credentials": {
    "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
    "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
    "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
    "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
}
```

#### Use these values in your credentials file:

```
[assumed-role]
aws_access_key_id = ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA
aws_secret_access_key = 9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI
aws_session_token = AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=
```

#### Use this temporary profile to execute the required command, like this:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:accountid:SISMANAGER-DEV-TOPIC --message testingForIamsDevUser --profile assumed-role --region=us-east-1
```

Comment: I already added `sts:AssumeRole` in both user policy and role policy.

Comment: Right. The user has the right to assume the policy but you still have to perform the assume policy action before you can use the role. The assume policy action provides you temporary credentials to act as the role that is assumed.

Comment: @divakar.scm I added an example to the answer of how this works